# Simple runtime profiler for executable files

Tags: c++17, boost

I'm sure there are several profilers written in C++ on here already, though with this one the goals are quite different. I attempted to make it as robust as possible, or 'fool-proof' if you will so that it is nearly impossible to crash via an unhandled exception or undefined behaviour.

It supports redirection of stdin, stdout and stderr to files as well.

```cpp
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdio>

typedef boost::chrono::steady_clock bench_clock;

// Defined map of acceptable arguments to integer for switch
const static std::unordered_map<std::string, int> string_map{
    {"--count", 1},
    {"--in", 2},
    {"--out", 2},
    {"--err", 2},
    {"process", 3}
};

// Return code of argument, or 0 if it's not defined
int string_case(std::string& s_case)
{
    return string_map.count(s_case) ? string_map.at(s_case) : 0;
}

// Check if string is numeric
bool is_digits(const std::string& str)
{
    return str.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namespace bp = boost::process;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "No runnable executable specified.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> arguments(argv + 1, argv + argc);
    auto it = std::begin(arguments);

    const auto executable_path = *it;

    std::vector<std::string> proc_arguments;
    unsigned long long count = 1;
    std::string string_num;
    std::string in_path; // Default initialized to ""
    std::string out_path;
    std::string err_path;
    
    for(const auto end = std::end(arguments); it+1 != end;)
    {
        switch(string_case(*(++it)))
        {
            default:
                std::cout << "Unexpected or illegal argument encountered: " << *it << "\n";
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            
            case 1:
                if (it + 1 == end)
                {
                    std::cout << "Unexpected end of argument list.\n";
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                string_num = *(++it);
            
                if(!is_digits(string_num))
                {
                    std::cout << "Argument for --count is either negative or contains non-numeric characters.\n";
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            
                try {
                    count = std::stoull(string_num);
                } catch(std::out_of_range&)
                {
                    std::cout << "Number too large for --count.\n";
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                } catch (std::invalid_argument&)
                {
                    std::cout << "--count can only accept numeric values.\n";
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                if(count == 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "Count must be larger than 0.\n";
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            
                break;
            
            case 2:
                if (it + 1 == end)
                {
                    std::cout << "Unexpected end of argument list.\n";
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                if (*it == "--in")
                    in_path = *(++it);
                else if (*it == "--out")
                    out_path = *(++it);
                else if (*it == "--err")
                    err_path = *(++it);

                break;

            case 3:
                while(it + 1 != end)
                {
                    proc_arguments.push_back(*(++it));
                }
            
                break;
        }
    }

    auto out_stream = out_path.empty() ? (bp::std_out > stdout) : (bp::std_out > out_path);
    auto err_stream = out_path.empty() ? (bp::std_err > stderr) : (bp::std_err > err_path);

    if (!out_path.empty()) {
        std::ofstream ofs_out(out_path);
        if (!ofs_out.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "STD_OUT file cannot be opened for writing.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        ofs_out.close();
    }

    if (!err_path.empty()) {
        std::ofstream ofs_err(err_path);
        if (!ofs_err.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "STD_ERR file cannot be opened for writing.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        ofs_err.close();
    }

    if (!in_path.empty()) {
        std::ifstream ifs_in(in_path);
        if (!ifs_in.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "STD_IN file cannot be opened for writing.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        ifs_in.close();
    }

    auto first = true;
    long double duration = 0;
    long double n = 1;
    int exit_code = 0;
    
    for (unsigned long long iter = 0; iter < count; iter++)
    {
        if (!in_path.empty() && !out_path.empty() && !err_path.empty() && count > 1) {
            std::string s(7, '\0');
            auto str_out = std::snprintf(&s[0], s.size(), "%.2f", (static_cast<double>(iter + 1) / static_cast<double>(count)) * 100);
            s.resize(str_out);
            std::cout << "Progress: " << iter + 1 << "/" << count << " ... " << s << "% done." << '\r' << std::flush;
        }
        
        std::unique_ptr<bp::child> proc;
        boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock> start;
        boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock> end;

        if(in_path.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "Child process may be awaiting input from stdin:\n";
        }
        
        try 
        {
            if (in_path.empty()) {
                start = bench_clock::now();
                proc = std::make_unique<bp::child>(bp::exe(executable_path), bp::std_in < stdin, out_stream, err_stream, bp::args(proc_arguments));
            }
            else {
                start = bench_clock::now();
                proc = std::make_unique<bp::child>(bp::exe(executable_path), bp::std_in < in_path, out_stream, err_stream, bp::args(proc_arguments));
            }
            (*proc).wait();
            end = bench_clock::now();
            exit_code = proc->exit_code();
            
        }
        catch (std::exception const& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(count == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Program completed with exit code " << exit_code << "\n";
        }

        if (iter == 1 && count >= 5)
            continue;

        n++;

        auto interval = static_cast<long double>(boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count());
        if (first) {
            duration += interval;
            first = false;
        }
        else
            duration = (duration * (n - 1) + interval) / n;
    }

    if(exit_code != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Warning, program may have crashed or thrown an exception mid run, profiling may be inaccurate.\n";
    }

    if(duration <= 0)
        std::cout << "\nMeasured duration: " << duration*1000 << " nanoseconds\n";
    else if(duration <= 1000)
        std::cout << "\nMeasured duration: " << duration << " microseconds\n";
    else if(duration <= 1000000)
        std::cout << "\nMeasured duration: " << duration / 1000 << " milliseconds\n";
    else
        std::cout << "\nMeasured duration: " << duration / 1000000 << " seconds\n";
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Would be happy for any feedback as to what can further be improved!
A readme with running instructions is [available on my github page](https://github.com/slobodaapl/Simple-executable-profiler) for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be more of a "timer" than a "profiler". (It provides no information about what is actually taking time inside the child process).

---

**Program structure**:

- We could make the program more readable by moving nearly all of the code out of `main`. We should have separate functions for parsing the command line args, and doing the actual timing. e.g.:

  ```
   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       auto options = parse_args(argc, argv); // returns std::optional<program_options>

       if (!options)
           return EXIT_FAILURE;

       run_process(options.value());
   }
  ```
- There are other places where code should be split into separate functions, e.g. parsing an unsigned int from a string, outputting progress, launching the child process.

---

**Parsing arguments**:

- If the user enters invalid arguments, it's common to show usage instructions, with a list of valid arguments, rather than just an error message.
- I don't think there's much benefit to looking up the argument strings in a map, translating the string into an `int`, and then using that `int` in a switch statement.

  We can put the argument into a `std::string` (or `std::string_view`) and then do `if (arg == "--count") { ... } else if (arg == "--in") { ... } ...` instead.
- [`std::stoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) will parse partial strings to unsigned integers. We should probably ensure that the whole string was used, to avoid something like "123.~sdfkshjidf" being accepted as "123". We can do that by checking the 2nd argument (`pos`) indicates the end of the string after the function call.

  With that check in place, we probably don't need the `is_digits` check beforehand.
- Doing `*(++it)` and comparing `it + 1 == end` is perhaps a little unusual. A more common idiom is to check for `it == end` before reading, and then do `*it++` to read from and increment the iterator.

We can make the intent of the code a bit clearer by parsing individual types in separate functions, e.g. `parse_string` or `parse_ull`. I'd probably go for something like:

```
struct program_options
{
    std::string m_exe_path;
    std::uint64_t m_count = 1;
    std::string m_in_path, m_out_path, m_err_path;
    std::vector<std::string> m_process_args;
};

std::optional<program_options> parse_args(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto print_usage = [&] ()
    {
        std::cout << "usage: ...\n";
    };
    
    auto parse_string = [&] (char**& arg, char** end, char const* error_str) -> std::optional<std::string>
    {
        if (arg == end)
        {
            std::cout << error_str << "not enough arguments.\n";
            print_usage();
            return { };
        }

        return *arg++;
    };

    auto parse_ull = [&] (char**& arg, char** end, char const* error_str) -> std::optional<std::size_t>
    {
        if (arg == end)
        {
            std::cout << error_str << "not enough arguments.\n";
            print_usage();
            return { };
        }

        try
        {
            auto str = std::string(*arg++);
            auto pos = std::size_t{ 0 };
            auto value = std::stoull(str, &pos);

            if (pos != str.size())
            {
                std::cout << error_str << "expected an integer.\n";
                print_usage();
                return { };
            }

            return value;
        }
        catch (std::invalid_argument&)
        {
            std::cout << error_str << "expected an integer.\n";
            print_usage();
            return { };
        }
        catch (std::out_of_range&)
        {
            std::cout << error_str << "value out of valid range.\n";
            print_usage();
            return { };
        }
    };

    auto arg = argv + 1; // argv[0] is the current program name
    auto const end = argv + argc;

    auto options = program_options();

    auto exe_path = parse_string(arg, end, "Failed to read executable path: ");
    if (!exe_path) return { };
    options.m_exe_path = exe_path.value();

    for ( ; arg != end; )
    {
        auto arg_sv = std::string_view(*arg++);

        if (arg_sv == "--count")
        {
            auto count = parse_ull(arg, end, "Failed to read --count: ");
            if (!count) return { };
            options.m_count = count.value();
        }
        else if (arg_sv == "--in")
        {
            auto in_path = parse_string(arg, end, "Failed to read --in: ");
            if (!in_path) return { };
            options.m_in_path = in_path.value();
        }
        else if (arg_sv == "--out")
        {
            auto out_path = parse_string(arg, end, "Failed to read --out: ");
            if (!out_path) return { };
            options.m_out_path = out_path.value();
        }
        else if (arg_sv == "--err")
        {
            auto err_path = parse_string(arg, end, "Failed to read --err: ");
            if (!err_path) return { };
            options.m_err_path = err_path.value();
        }
        else if (arg_sv == "process")
        {
            options.m_process_args.assign(arg, end);
            arg = end;
        }
    }

    return options;
}
```

(C++ is always a bit awkward for things like this. We either have to use exception handling for flow control (although weird user input is never really "exceptional"), a boolean return value (or error code) paired with a reference output argument (kinda old-fashioned), or `std::optional` (annoyingly verbose).)

---

I don't think there's a lot of point opening and then closing the input / output / error files before hand. Even if it succeeds here, it could still fail later.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome feedback! I will make sure to learn from it into the future. The `strtoull` had to be parsed with `is_digit()` because it can convert negative numbers which is unwanted behavior, without throwing an exception. So instead of adding a separate check for '-' at the beginning I just parsed the whole thing. As for opening and closing the input/output files.. boost process itself doesn't report any issues when trying to open them even if ti fails, so it's good to have at least a small check in place to see if the file can at least be created, I think